# How to deal with url for google while using ajax

Tags: html, ajax, url

My question is regarding URL on my site. I am wondering how to write usable URL for Google search engine while using AJAX on my site.

I'm using AJAX to minimize the resource usage on my site. It also prevent the page from flashing every time you hit a link.

But I also made a Rewrite rule to accept more common URL's. These URL's could be use to get to a document in my site.

```
<a  href ="http://example.com/article/my-new-article-1-1.php">Read it here</a>
```

My URL's are as follow:

```
<a  onClick="MyAjaxFunc()" href ="#">this is my link</a>
```

Its working great and fast just the way I like it. But what will happen when Google try to index my site?

Is there a way to make my URL work with AJAX on my site but render a more Google friendly URL.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: look at `url rewriting`, if you are using apache2 you have to put it in .htaccess.

Comment: This might help https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/learn-more and this too https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification

Comment: Im not looking to use Rewrited url on my site but only for google indexing.