# JavaScript vs No JavaScript links and forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

A few days ago I posted this question:

[My last question about ajax link vs normal link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34715139/how-to-deal-with-url-for-google-while-using-ajax?noredirect=1#comment57176505_34715139)

It was about making links work for JavaScript enable browser (AJAX) and normal link for non-JavaScript browsers or crawlers.

Now I found that this method work for me and is also recommended by Google. This is what I do:

```
<a href="/some/page.php" onClick="jsfunction():return false">My Link</a>
```

Now what I like about this is that it is working exactly how I need it to work.
But if I was to use an event handler with jQuery. I would do something like this:

```
 <a href="/some/page.php" id="mylink">My Link</a>

<script>
  $("#mylink").live(\'click\', function(){
  my_function();
  }) 
</script>
```

I want to know how to prevent my page from reaching the target `/some/page.php` when JavaScript is enable and not using the onClick event with a return false like the previous case.

I was also wondering how to do the same with forms. When I click the submit button and JavaScript is enable I don't want the form to perform the action.

I'm trying to make a site that is working with and without JavaScript enabled browser. The only difference is that JavaScript enabled browser will use AJAX and the others not.

Comment: Have you tried returning false from your event handler?

Comment: Note that [`live()` has been deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/live/) for many years.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`preventDefault()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/), like this:

```
<script>
    $("#mylink").live('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        my_function();
    });
</script>
```

Note that you have to have `event` as a parameter to the `function` for this sample code to work. Also, I don't know why you had escaped your `'` (maybe this code is generated by another script somehow?), but you don't need it unless you're doing something strange.

---

This part isn't technically your answer, but it's also important: [`live()` is deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/live/), as pointed out in the comments. The best way to do this is with event delegation and [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), like this:

```
<script>
    $('body').on('click', '#mylink', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        my_function();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @ZeroG Yep. It just stops the browser from doing whatever it would do by default in response to a given action.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you should use method [`event.preventDefault()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/).